# C# - How To Make Loading gif Continue to Rotate

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, gif

So I am working in Visual Studio in C# and I have a gif of a loading image that I will need when I make a call to a web service because it takes a minute or two to get the data needed. The gif rotates fine but my problem is that when it makes the call to the web service, the gif stops rotating. Does anyone know how to keep it rotating while the call is being made? Preferably being able to this in C# and not HTML.

Comment: Can you share the code of what you've done so far?

Comment: @Ignas I can't really share my code to the web service call because its too large but the gif is inserting using a PictureBox Windows Forms but rotates fine throughout until the web service is called then freezes

Comment: Is it a desktop app? Are you running UI/gif in a separate thread from web service call?

Comment: Make the callback Asynchronous.

Comment: @Ignas I don't think so. The gif and web service call don't really have any relation other than they are both stored in the same folder

Comment: @JohnPeters what do you mean by this? Can you give an example?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=async+await

Answer (score 0):

You can get the behavior you are looking for by using c#'s async/await. Here is an example that will not block the UI thread.

This is the code-behind for a form that has: A picture box with a rotating gif in it, a label control to report status, and a button to start the process.

```
private async void btnCallWebService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblStatus.Text = "Running method...";
    string result = await LongRunningMethod();
    lblStatus.Text = result;
}

private async Task<string> LongRunningMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    return "Method complete";
}
```

In this instance the LongRunningMethod would be your web service call that takes a long time. You should make your web service method call async, and make the return type of Task.

Edit:

You can return any type from the async call. You mentioned that your web call was something in the form of: Result result = WebServiceCall(login, password);

You can just create a method that calls the web service method asynchronously.

```
private async Task<Result> WebServiceCallAsync(string login, string password) 
{
     return WebServiceCall(login, password);
}

then you would use this method like:
Result result = await WebServiceCallAsync("user name", "password");
```

Comment: Ehz can you return something else other than a string from the web call? Because I have a object returned such as Result result = WebServiceCall(login, password). How could I incorporate this into your solution because I am getting errors currently

Comment: Ehz I followed what you said but am receiving an error line under Result result = await WebServiceCallAsync(...).  It says "the 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'".  Any suggestions why?

Comment: notice in the first example given, the handler for the button click also has "async" applied to it. You need to add "async" to the event handler or any other methods in the chain that will call WebServiceCallAsync

Comment: Ehz this seems to remove the error line but my gif still freezes when the Web Service is called. I turn it visible before the web service is called and then turn its visible to false after the web service is done. Is there somewhere I must put the loadingImg.Visible = true & false for it to continue to rotate? Aside: the WebServiceCallAsync has a green line underneath saying "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread."

Comment: You will need to show the code that you have so far, incorporating what was added with async

Comment: Ehz my code is that exact same as the code you provided except I have loadingImg.Visible = true and loadingImg.Visible = false before and after return WebServiceCall(login, password)